# highchart.. browser stop working on loading a chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am adding highchart series dynamically . my setting are like below .

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
    "name": "Ratingovertijrrrrrrrrr",
    "CID": 59,
    "type": 1,
    "chart": {
        "type": "area",
        "zoomType": "xy",
        "animation": true,
        "renderTo": "CHART_01"
    },
    "colors": ["#fae570", "#e4b9b9", "#dc7474"],
    "exporting": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "legend": {
        "enabled": true,
        "floating": false,
        "layout": "horizontal",
        "align": "center",
        "verticalAlign": "bottom",
        "backgroundColor": ""
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "series": {
            "allowPointSelect": false,
            "animation": true,
            "showInLegend": true,
            "dataLabels": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "stacking": "normal"
        }
    },
    "subtitle": {
        "text": "over tijd",
        "style": {
            "fontFamily": "Arial",
            "fontSize": "14px",
            "fontWeight": "normal",
            "fontStyle": "normal",
            "color": "#000000"
        }
    },
    "title": {
        "text": "Rating",
        "style": {
            "fontFamily": "Arial",
            "fontSize": "18px",
            "fontWeight": "normal",
            "fontStyle": "normal",
            "color": "#000000"
        }
    },
    "tooltip": {
        "enabled": true,
        "shared": true,
        "animation": true,
        "crosshairs": [true, false],
        "backgroundColor": "#79e538",
        "formatter": function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + ':</b>' + this.y;
        }
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "title": {
            "text": "Date",
            "enabled": false,
            "style": {
                "fontFamily": "Arial",
                "fontSize": "8px",
                "fontWeight": "normal",
                "fontStyle": "normal",
                "color": ""
            }
        },
        "type": "datetime",
        "minRange": "60000",
        "startOfWeek": "1",
        "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
            "millisecond": "%H:%M:%S.%L",
            "second": "%H:%M:%S",
            "minute": "%H:%M",
            "hour": "%H:%M",
            "day": "%e. %b",
            "week": "%e. %b",
            "month": "%b '%y",
            "year": "%Y"
        },
        "categories": [""],
        "labels": {
            "enabled": true,
            "align": "center",
            "rotation": "0",
            "x": "0",
            "y": "15"
        }
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "title": {
            "text": "Rating",
            "enabled": false,
            "style": {
                "fontFamily": "Arial",
                "fontSize": "8px",
                "fontWeight": "normal",
                "fontStyle": "normal",
                "color": ""
            }
        },
        "type": "linear",
        "minRange": "",
        "startOfWeek": "1",
        "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
            "millisecond": "%H:%M:%S.%L",
            "second": "%H:%M:%S",
            "minute": "%H:%M",
            "hour": "%H:%M",
            "day": "%e. %b",
            "week": "%e. %b",
            "month": "%b '%y",
            "year": "%Y"
        },
        "categories": [""],
        "labels": {
            "enabled": true,
            "align": "center",
            "rotation": "",
            "x": "",
            "y": ""
        }
    },
    "series": [{
        "data": [0],
        "name": "Loading...",
        "loadingSeries": true
    }],
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    }
});
```

`CHART_01` is container id . Initially loading will show ..after that ajax send to server to get series list .. and series add dynamically on success callback of ajax function .

**The issue is browser stop working** .

---

edit :

When I changed type into `linear`

```
"xAxis": {       
        "type": "linear",
        "minRange": "0"
```

it working ... What is issue with `"type": "datetime"`?

Comment: If this happens after you load series, add series example. Especially data.

Comment: You didn't show us the most pertinent piece of code; your ajax call and how you add the series...

Comment: @PawełFus no it happens on page load

Comment: Still, ad data sample for that chart. Second thing is that you are setting a lot of options which won't work together, for example why you are setting type for xAxis to datetime, and then setting categories? Decide which one you want to use, the same applies to yAxis.

Comment: @PawełFus I added it in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kXu6R/ .. you can uncomment `******** uncomment this part ******` in xAxis options .. and run jsfiddle .. you can see my issue !

Comment: And read my previous comment once again - you can use or CATEGORIES or datetime axis. For example, minRange: 60000 means you want to have at least 60000 different categories on this chart..

Comment: @PawełFus thanks you so much .. these chart options are adding by backend admin.. categories default value `[""]` .. and fixed into `null` .. it works now :)

Comment: @PawełFus you add it as answer .. I will mark and up vote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRoblem was with setting xAxis. In Highcharts it's not possible to set in the same time categorized axis and `datetime`. Also when setting `minRange` to some high values like 60 000 for categorized chart, Highcharts expect to display at least 60 000 categories, which is impossible to display 60 000 of labels for xAxis on a chart with width ~1000px.